# Switch partition says index needs to include partitioned column

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

> 'ALTER TABLE SWITCH' statement failed. The table 'dbo.test' is 
>   partitioned while index 'IX_test' is not partitioned."

When I run `switch partition`, I get this error. To resolve this error, `IX_test` index should have the partitioned column included in its definition. But if we include the partitioned column in the index, will this decrease the performance?

Example: We have Table X which has index on columns A, B, and C and it is partitioned on column D. We create one more table called X1 with the same schema as X. We will use this for a partition switch operation between them (X and X1).

As the index is not on column D (it's on A, B, C), I am getting the error above.
**Is it good to add the partitioned column (i.e., D) to the index as shown below?**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T_MSB_Pseudo ON dbo.T_MSB_Pseudo
(
    A, B, C
)
INCLUDE
(
    D
)
ON PRIMARY
```

Will this decrease the performance? Are there other alternatives to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit for readability.

Answer (score 3):

SWITCHing partitions requires the switched tables are pretty much* identical in every way
So make them so.

The point of partition switching it to be able to swap a few pointers to swap data in and out without any actual processing or checks or data movement. So there are rules.

From MSDN ["Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), 2 key points

> Partitions must be on the same column
>
> Nonclustered indexes must be defined and must be identical

Comment: But including the partitioned columns will effect the actual performance or the purpose of creating the non-clustered indewx..

Comment: Why will it? Either you want partition switching or you don't

Comment: Exactly. And without partition switching the question is - why use partitioning at all? Not a joke - partitions are not for query speed. They are for data maintenance.